# Logic App Invoke an HTTP request (HTTP with Azure AD) base64

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've added an action Invoke an HTTP request (HTTP with Azure AD)

***Method**: Post

***Url of the request** = some endpoint

**Body of the request** = a regular json string like { "teste":"1"}

**Header** = Content-Type:application/json

[image]

And for some reason, it is trying to add a base64 for this request (this picture below is the request result )

[image]

Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation with this connector.

The connector encodes the request body into base64 encoding, hence it should be used to call backend services which expect the request body in this format. You cannot use this connector to call a backend service that expects the request body in raw binary format.

It is mentioned in the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/#known-issues-and-limitations

If you are not calling a backend service hosted in On-prem machine from consumption logic app, you can use normal HTTP action. It supports Azure AD authentication. With standard logic app, you can connect to resources through VNET as well. So, its possible to invoke services in on-prem via HTTP action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

Hope this helps.